# Don't close SQL connection until is has finished reading

Tags: c#, sql

I have the below code, which works, but is only reading the top row of the DB and then terminating. The array should hold 3 pieces of data, but it only holds one.

I think this is because it is not looping.

How do you say for the code to carry on running until it has no more data to read?

```
SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ssConnectionString);
conn1.Open();

SqlCommand command1 = conn1.CreateCommand();
command1.CommandText = "SELECT FeedURL FROM [dbo].[Feeds]";

rssFeeds.Add(command1.ExecuteScalar());

conn1.Close();
```

Comment: You want `ExecuteReader()` and loop.

Comment: if you have more records then you need to wrap your rssFeeds or datareader within a `while` loop

Comment: Looping what? `ExecuteScalar` returns one single value or `null`

Comment: `T.S` read the comments closer.. what `SLaks and I` are saying are the exact same thing .. don't confuse the issue please

Comment: What is "rsFeeds"?  And you should use the "Using" structure and load a dataset or datatable.

Answer (score 8):

By default `ExecuteScalar()` will only ever return one value.  You would need to create a `DataReader`, and then loop through the results using `command1.ExecuteReader()`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use ExecuteReader for your problem. In this example that I took from MSDN is consuming the connection with using statement because SqlConnection class has some unmanaged resources. If you have more questions about using and Finalizers also check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#How).

How to use ExecuteReader, you can check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
static void HasRows(SqlConnection connection)
{
    using (connection)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
          "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName FROM Categories;",
          connection);
        connection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", reader.GetInt32(0),
                    reader.GetString(1));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will also work for the Op provided he understands most importantly the reader.HasRows check first prior to Iterating thru the rest of the results set.. good example +1

Answer (score 1):

```
conn1.Open();
string query = "select feedurl from [dbo].[feeds]";
DataSet DS = new DataSet();
SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(query,conn1);
adapt.Fill(DS);
if (DS != null)
{
     if (DS.Tables[0].rows.Count > 0 )
    {
        foreach(DataRow DR in DS.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            string temp = DR['columnname'];
        }
    }
{
```

Comment: Also when you are done, you might want to dispose of the SqlDataAdapter and Dataset by using adapt.Dispose() and DS.Dispose()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//method to make this code reusable
//the returned data set is accessible even if the underlying connection is closed
//NB: that means data's held in memory; so beware of your resource usage
    public DataSet ExecuteSQLToDataSet(string ssConnectionString, string query, string name)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("Tables");
        using (SqlConnection conn1 = new SqlConnection(ssConnectionString))
        {
            conn1.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, objConn);
            sda.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source, name);
            sda.Fill(ds, name);
        } //using statement will close and dispose the connection for you
        return ds;
    }


//example usage

    DataSet ds = ExecuteSQLToDataSet(ssConnectionString, "SELECT FeedURL FROM [dbo].[Feeds]", "Feeds"); //nb: name doesn't have to match table name; you can call it what you like; naming is useful if you wanted to add other result sets to the same data set

    //DataTable tblFeeds = ds.Tables["Feeds"]; //if you want to access the above query by name

    foreach (DataTable tbl in ds.Tables)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dr in tbl.Rows) //tblFeeds.Rows if you did that instead of looping through all tables
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(dr["FeedURL"].ToString()); //you can specify a named column
            Console.WriteLine(dr[0].ToString()); //or just use the index
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Console.ReadLine();
```

More Detail: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314145